# How to finish processing a Facebook Canvas payment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, canvas

Let me start off by saying that without finding any tutorials for facebook asp.net mvc canvas payment tutorials, I have managed to figure it out over time and I have a callback once the payment goes through that works like a charm but what I'm stumped by is what to do for the user after payment is confirmed. My current jquery code is below and this is what I created based on some javascript code I found but nothing works so I'm either doing something wrong or I just don't know what to do. Please let me know what to do to let the user know that the payment is complete.

UPDATE: This is more of a edit to my question but how can I redirect them to a completion page that just gives them a basic success message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '@Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook.GlobalFacebookConfiguration.Configuration.AppId',
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            });

            function buy() {
                var obj = {
                    method: 'pay',
                    action: 'purchaseitem',
                    product: 'https://website.net/product.html',
                    request_id: '@ViewBag.HashKey'
                };

                FB.ui(obj, function (data) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        url: "/Home/finishOrder",
                        data: data,
                        async: true
                    });
                }, callback);
            }
            buy();

        };

        function callback(data) {
            if (!data) {
                alert("There was an error processing your payment. Please try again!");
                return;
            }

            console.log('Verifying payment', data);

            if (data.error_code) {
                if (data.error_code != 1383010) {
                    alert("There was an error processing your payment." + data.error_message + " Error code:" + data.error_code);
                }
                return;
            }

            alert("The payment is successful!");
        }

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was trying to combine two different callback functions with my code. Here is my finished code for anyone interested. This calls a method which returns a message for the user.

```
function buy() {
                var obj = {
                    method: 'pay',
                    action: 'purchaseitem',
                    product: 'https://website.net/product.html',
                    request_id: '@ViewBag.HashKey'
                };

                FB.ui(obj, function (data) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        url: "/Home/finishOrder",
                        data: data,
                        async: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data.message);
                    }
                    });
                });
            }
            buy();
```